# CLoud Datastore: Transactions implementation details and monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I've recently started to use transactions. However I'm missing some pieces of documentation.

Up till now I had a regular `save` and `get` functions which were calling the datastore. I was measuring these ones for latency.

When working with transactions when do I actually hit the network in the following code *typescript) (please see comments inline)

```
 public async transactionTest(key: any, data: any) {
const transaction: DatastoreTransaction = this.datastore.transaction();
await transaction.run();
// is the save already a network call? I would assume that it's not.
transaction.save({
  key: key,
  data: data
});

// I'm trying to fetch the entity which I've just saved above which is not yet commited 
// This works 
// I assumed that GET is only a network call,
//  does it first try to fetch the objects saved in the transaction? 
var entity = await transaction.get(key);

await transaction.commit();
```

}

What functions on the transaction actually perform a method call and are worth being measured for latency and errors?

I'd expect ant `get` or `query`. But how about `save`?